# Access Violation When Using Indy OpenSSL and MySql

Tags: delphi, indy

Using MySql 8.0.16, Delphi 10.3 Rio, and the standard version of Indy that comes with it.

I'm using an instance of `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` with an instance of `TIdHttpServer`, using OpenSSL 1.0.2s downloaded from Fulgan. All of my Indy components are created in code at runtime.

Everything appears to work until I close the app and get an Access Violation in `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Unload()` which gets called from the `finalization` section of the `IdSSLOpenSSL.pas` file.

> Project rasied exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION'

The stack trace is as follows:

```
IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Unload
IdSSLOpenSSL.UnloadOpenSSLLibrary
IdSSLOpenSSL.Finalization
System.FinalizeUnits
System._Halt()
MayApp.MayApp
:0000000076DC556D; C:\Windows\system32\kernel.dll
:0000000076F2385D; ntdll.dll
```

The crash is here:

```
if Assigned(ERR_remove_thread_state) then begin
  ERR_remove_thread_state(nil); <-- Access Violation here
end
```

I am currently freeing the `TIdHTTPServer` First, then the `IOHandler`.

The problem occurs when I connect to a MySql database. It looks like libmysql also uses the error queue for the main thread and it also frees the queue by calling `ERR_remove_thread_state()`. The minimum code to reproduce is here:

```pascal
program OpenSSLIssue;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.IoUtils, System.JSON, WinApi.Windows,
  WinApi.Messages, System.Generics.Collections, IdServerIOHandler, IdSSL, IdGlobal,
  IdSSLOpenSSL, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer,
  IdUDPBase, IdUDPServer,IdSocketHandle, IdCustomHTTPServer, IdHTTPServer, IdContext,
  IdCoderMIME, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders, FireDac.Comp.Client, FireDac.Phys.MySQL,
  FireDAC.Stan.Def;

type
  TEndPoint = class
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    FIP: String;
    FPort: WORD;
    FProtocol: String;
    FServer: TIdHttpServer;
    FIOHandler: TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL;
    procedure QuerySSLPort(APort: Word; var AUseSSL: Boolean);
    function SSLVerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509; AOk: Boolean; ADepth,  AError: Integer): Boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AIP: String; APort: WORD; AProtocol: String);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Start: Boolean;
    procedure Stop;
  end;

constructor TEndPoint.Create(AIP: String; APort: WORD; AProtocol: String);
begin
  var LPath := ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)));
  IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(LPath);

  FIP := AIP;
  FPort := APort;
  FProtocol := AProtocol.ToUpper;

  FServer := TIdHttpServer.Create(nil);
  FServer.DefaultPort := APort;
  FServer.OnQuerySSLPort := QuerySSLPort;

  if 'HTTPS' = FProtocol then
  begin
    FIOHandler := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;

    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))+ 'device.crt';
    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))+ 'myDevice.key';
    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))+ 'myRootCA.pem';
    FIOHandler.OnVerifyPeer := SSLVerifyPeer;
    FServer.IOHandler := FIOHandler;
  end;

  var LBinding := FServer.Bindings.Add;
  LBinding.IP := AIP;
  LBinding.Port := APort;
end;

destructor TEndPoint.Destroy;
begin
  FServer.Free;
  if nil <> FIOHandler then
    FIOHandler.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TEndPoint.QuerySSLPort(APort: Word; var AUseSSL: Boolean);
begin
  AUseSSL := 'HTTPS' = FProtocol;
end;

function TEndPoint.SSLVerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509; AOk: Boolean; ADepth,  AError: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := AOK;
end;

function TEndPoint.Start: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FALSE;
  try
    FServer.Active := TRUE;
    Result := TRUE;
  except
  end;
end;

procedure TEndPoint.Stop;
begin
  try
    FServer.Active := FALSE;
  except
    //Suppress any exceptions as sockets are closed off
  end;
end;

function GetConnection(ADatabaseName, AUserName, APAssword, ADatabase, AHost: String): TFDConnection;
begin
  var LConnectionDef := FDManager.ConnectionDefs.FindConnectionDef(ADatabaseName + '_Connection');
  if nil = LConnectionDef then
  begin
    var LParams := TStringList.Create;
    LParams.Add('User_Name=' + AUserName);
    LParams.Add('Password=' + APassword);
    LParams.Add('Server=' + AHost);
    LParams.Add('Database=' + ADatabase);
    FDManager.AddConnectionDef(ADatabaseName + '_Connection', 'MYSQL', LParams);
  end else
  begin
    var LIndex := LConnectionDef.Params.IndexOfName('Server');
    LConnectionDef.Params[LIndex] := AHost;
    LConnectionDef.Params.UserName := AUserName;
    LConnectionDef.Params.Password := APassword;
    LConnectionDef.Params.Database := ADatabase;
  end;

  Result := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  Result.LoginPrompt := FALSE;
  Result.DriverName := 'MYSQL';
  Result.ConnectionDefName := ADatabaseName + '_Connection';
end;

(* Create the DQL in MySql Workbeanch with the following:

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTestDB`;

USE MyTestDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestTable`(
    `VersionID` int NOT NULL,
    `VerMajor` int NOT NULL,
    `VerMinor` int NOT NULL,
    `VerRelease` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`VersionID`)
);

*)
begin
  var DriverLink := TFDPhysMYSQLDriverLink.Create(nil);
  DriverLink.VendorLib := String.Format('%s\libmysql.dll',[ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFileDir( ParamStr(0) ))]);

  try
    var FEndpoint := TEndPoint.Create('127.0.0.1', 8200, 'https');
    try
      FEndpoint.Start;

      var LConn := GetConnection('MyTestDB', 'root', 'rootPasswd', 'MyTestDB', 'localhost');
      try
        LConn.Open;
        WriteLn('Connection Open');
        Sleep(1000);
        LConn.Close;
      finally
        LConn.Free;
      end;
      FEndpoint.Stop;
    finally
      FEndpoint.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

  DriverLink.Free;

end.
```

Comment: ERR_remove_thread_state is a function pointer. I don't think they are freed as such. In addition the call to the open ssl function pointers before this call seems to work.

Comment: This _can_ happen if you explicitly free something that is later freed by its owner, or try to free something that was already freed by its owner. What happens if you jump into `ERR_remove_thread_state`? Where do you end up?

Comment: Updated with stack trace info. ERR_remove_thread_state appears to be a function in one of the openssl dlls (libeay32.dll to be exact). Also the IO Handler was created with a nil owner (so I free it expliciltly). 
However the error happens after all the components are freed, as the app shuts down.

Comment: *the error happens after all the components are freed* means that you're freeing something inappropriately that some other code is trying to free as part of it's cleanup. You need to post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue if you want us to help you identify what that might be. Can you reproduce it by a simple test app that includes nothing but your component creation and cleanup code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this is the order in which the finalization sections of the units are run. This is dictated by the order in which the Units appear in the uses clause. The initialization sections are run in the order they appear in the uses. The finalization sections are run in *reverse* order.

In this order the finalize section of IdSSLOpenSSL.pas will be run *after* libmysql.dll is unloaded by FireDAC and will result in an AcessViolation when Indy attempts to cleanup and unload OpenSSL:

```
uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.IoUtils, System.JSON, WinApi.Windows,
  WinApi.Messages, System.Generics.Collections, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDac.Phys.MySQL,
  IdServerIOHandler, IdSSL, IdGlobal, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer,
  IdTCPServer, IdUDPBase, IdUDPServer,IdSocketHandle, IdCustomHTTPServer, IdHTTPServer,
  IdContext, IdCoderMIME, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders,

  //finlaize section of IdSSLOpenSSL will be run after 
  //libmysql.dll is unloaded byFireDAC

  IdSSLOpenSSL,
  FireDac.Comp.Client;
```

In this order the finalize section of IdSSLOpenSSL.pas will be run *before* libmysql.dll is unloaded by FireDAC and there will be no errors:

```
uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.IoUtils, System.JSON, WinApi.Windows,
  WinApi.Messages, System.Generics.Collections, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDac.Phys.MySQL,
  IdServerIOHandler, IdSSL, IdGlobal, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer,
  IdTCPServer, IdUDPBase, IdUDPServer,IdSocketHandle, IdCustomHTTPServer, IdHTTPServer,
  IdContext, IdCoderMIME, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders,

  //finlaize section of IdSSLOpenSSL will be run before 
  //libmysql.dll is unloaded byFireDAC

  FireDac.Comp.Client,
  IdSSLOpenSSL;
```

Comment: Changing the `uses` order, wouldn't making MySql call `ERR_remove_thread_state()` after Indy has already called it just produce the same crash but inside of libmysql instead? Is it even safe to call `ERR_remove_thread_state()` multiple times per thread?

Comment: It may throw an exception inside libmysql, but that may handle it since there is no exception showing up in the application itself. Or possibly there is a way to check the threads error queue state before calling it. I'm not an openssl expert, so I'm not sure.